# C String input confusion

Tags: c, string, pointers

C really isn't my strong point and after reading 3 chapters of a book on the subject and spending ages trying to get stuff working it just doesn't:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *a,*b;
int main( )
{
     char input[10];
     fgets(input,sizeof input, stdin);
     a = input;
     fgets(input,sizeof input, stdin);
     b = input;
     printf("%s : %s",a,b);

}
```

I've isolated the problem from my main project. This code is meant to read in two strings and then print them however it seems to be setting a and b to point to input. Sample output from this code when A and B are entered is(don't worry about the \n's i can remove them):

```
A
B
B
 : B
```

How do i store the value of input in another variable eg. a or b so that in the above case

```
A
B
A
 : B
```

Is output?

NOTE: I don't want a or b to point to another variable i want to store a string in them:

```
a = "A";
b = "B";
```

would be the string literal equivalent.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to either declare `a` and `b` as separate arrays as large as your input array, or dynamically allocate memory to them.  Either way, you'll have to use `strcpy()` to copy the contents of one string to another:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char input[10], a[10], b[10];
  fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
  strcpy(a, input);
  fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
  strcpy(b, input);
  printf("%s : %s\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a is a pointer to input, as is b. Setting a = input just sets a to point to input.

So your calls to `fgets` affect the same buffer.

You should use two separate arrays for A and B, and copy the data from input into A and B.

> NOTE: I don't want a or b to point to another variable i want to store a string in them:
>
> a = "A";
>
> b = "B";
>
> would be the string literal equivalent.

Unfortunately, C doesn't quite work the way you think it does. You're too used to higher-level lanaguages who do the copying for you.

In C, if you want A and B to contain data, you have to specify the data container, and *put* the data in there.

For example:

```
int main( ) 
{ 
     char input[10]; 
     char aData[10];
     char bData[10];     
     fgets(input,sizeof input, stdin); 
     strcpy(aData, input);
     fgets(input,sizeof input, stdin); 
     strcpy(bData, input);
     printf("%s : %s",aData,bData);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Yeah higher level languages are too helpful sometimes :D

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 different char buffer arrays.

A pointer is just a varaible that holds a memory address.

So in the following code:

```
a = input;
```

and

```
b = input;
```

Both `a` and `b` hold the same memory address, that memory address is the address of the first element of the array.

This is the correct code:

```
char input1[10];
char input2[10];
fgets(input,sizeof input1, stdin);
fgets(input,sizeof input2, stdin);
printf("%s : %s",input1, input2);
```

Also when you take `sizeof(pointer)` you will get 4 on an x86 system always. You don't get the size of the element you are pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use separate arrays for each input, so the second input doesn't overwrite the first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( )
{
     char a[10];
     char b[10];
     fgets(a,sizeof a, stdin);
     fgets(b,sizeof b, stdin);
     printf("%s : %s",a,b);

}
```

Comment: There isn't any difference in C. Strings are represented by pointers to sequences of characters (terminated by a zero byte). You could always copy the string into another buffer (e.g., one allocated dynamically) before reusing `input` for the second read, but that takes more code...

Comment: That would work for the example but not for the actual project. In the project i want to store input and then later set a to it.

Comment: You can't set a to hold more than one char[], but you're welcome to try.